# How to sync WP8 with Windows?

Tags: zune, 8.0, sync

I plugged in my HTC 8X into Windows 8 and not much happened. Zune and Windows Media Player do not recognise it as a device. I can see the contents of the device in Windows Explorer and it is listed in *PC Settings -> Devices*. Windows Phone Connector on Mac seems to work with it.

How can I sync my music (and perform other Zune functionality) on a Windows Phone 8 device to a PC?

Comment: WMP should recognize your phone as plugable media device. At least it does for my Lumia 920. However, I want to note that there is an entry on [UserVoice](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3342058-continue-to-use-zune-for-media-sync-in-wp) to continue zune support. It already received about 10k votes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For Windows Phone 8, you can no longer use Zune to sync to your PC.

With Windows 8, they've instead provided the [Windows Phone app](http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/en-CA/app/windows-phone/0e0fbaf6-fd99-4046-b494-9ce469ae3009) or the [Windows Phone 8 app for desktop](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/how-to/wp8/windows-phone-app-for-desktop).

Either one will sync music, photos, videos, and ringtones between your phone and your computer. They will also sync with iTunes.

---

Additional information for other O/S versions:

To sync Windows Phone 8 with Windows 8 RT, use the [Windows Phone app](http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/en-CA/app/windows-phone/0e0fbaf6-fd99-4046-b494-9ce469ae3009).

To sync Windows Phone 8 with Windows 7, use the [Windows Phone 8 app for desktop](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/how-to/wp8/windows-phone-app-for-desktop).

To sync Windows Phone 8 with a Mac, use [Windows Phone app for Mac](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/how-to/wp8/windows-phone-app-for-mac).

For the Windows 8 or the above 3 O/S versions, you can also use Windows Explorer to copy things between your phone and computer.

For other O/S versions, your only option is Windows Explorer.

Comment: how about connecting a Windows Phone 8 to a Windows 7? Will Zune work for this?

Comment: @franklins - No. Zune is no longer usable at all with Windows Phone 8. I've added info to my answer above for Windows 7 and other O/S versions.

Comment: You can also use Windows Media Player...although it is quite slow and I found it to create duplicates of existing songs.

Comment: It might be worth noting that the Windows Phone 8 App for Desktop is a bit limited, I've found that (for example) it will happily sync playlists but not actually sync the SONGS, why would I want the playlists without the actual songs? 8-(

Comment: Oh my god i've spent like a year trying to figure this out!! :@ Thank you ikessler!

Answer (score 1):

Go to File Explorer after you have plugged your phone.

You should be able to see a folder -> Phone -> Ringtones.

Copy the ringtones, and you are all set.