# How to get the album art displayed?

Tags: 8.0, sync, music

I have tried syncing my music using the [Windows Phone app](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1227/how-to-sync-wp8-with-windows) and Windows Media Player but none of the applications copy over the album art.

I am using Windows 8, my music is stored in iTunes and I have tried the following:

1. *Used the Windows Phone app to sync the iTunes music folder* - Copies all of the music but no album art.
2. *Used the iTunes sync option in Windows Phone app for desktop* - Crashes halfway through and the music that did get transferred has no album art.
3. *Used Windows Media Player* - Shows the album art in the desktop application but does not sync the art.

I live in a region where Xbox music is not available (Singapore), so not sure if that limits some of my options.

Comment: I had the exact same problem, try using MPAtool (found in windows phone store)

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: I can't see this app in the store - have you a link?

Comment: As requested in the comments here's a link to [MPATool](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/mpatool/a6056e5e-34bd-4098-9cd8-4ed5df611d97) Also [Mp3 Finder](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/mp3-finder-free/8147ea62-d090-433e-909b-6aa796937d71) has an album art feature.

Answer (score 4):

Album art that is correctly included in the files will be displayed on the device. If you're using MP3 files, be aware that MP3 have two different metadata formats ([ID3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3)), and Windows (and Windows Phone) only supports album art in one of them.

I'll recommend you use WMA or M4A instead of MP3, as these formats offer the same sound quality (if not better), and a single metadata format.

Also, note that album art displayed from a *Folder.jpg* or similar *file* will not be displayed on the phone. The album art **must be embedded in the music file**.

Comment: I use MediaMonkey to manually attach the graphics to the music files - that seems to work for me.